# MetaMask no longer working on my Chrome browser

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have learned that MetaMask no longer automatically links up to Web3 sites. Every time I now try to use my MetaMask to transfer fund from MyEtherWallet, I see that it is not connected to whatever site I'm trying to connect to and get this message: "MetaMask is not connected this site. To connect to a web3 site, find the connect button on their site." To put it simply, I have not been able to find any such button nor do I understand the complex (to me) coding advice I'm finding in my research on how to correct this problem. I am not a coder nor a sophisticated user. Is there any simpler way a non-coder can get this to work or should I disable MetaMask and go back to the old school way of making transfers directly from MyEtherWallet?

Comment: Voting to close. This is a question for MetaMask customer support.

Comment: https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/migration/using-metamask-with-mew/

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed. Similar users will likely find this question and whatever answers are given before they find anything else while researching solutions.

Comment: I will ask MetaMask support.

Comment: If you logout from MyEtherWallet the first time you login metamask will ask which accounts you want to authorize. From metamask in the top-left corner there is status line connected/not connected, clickin on that line should show which addresses were allowed to connect.